# TracedShapeArray in Jax

Tags: jax

Is there a reason why Jax can't do indexing for the vmapped function. I am getting the index error because jnp.take() is not actually taking the x,y co-ordinates for the vector containing these points. P and M below are the ndarray [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]] each.

```
@jnp.vectorize
def main(P, M, omega):
  g = 9.8
  k0 = (omega**2)/g
  print(jnp.take(M, jnp.array([0, 1])))
  #sqrt(sum(x**2 - y**2)) for two XYZ and PQR points
  r = jnp.sqrt(jnp.sum(jnp.square(jnp.take(P, jnp.array([0, 1])) - jnp.take(M, jnp.array([0, 1])))))  
  Z = P[2] + M[2]  # zp + zm 
  R = jnp.sqrt(jnp.sum(jnp.square(P-M))) 
  R1 = jnp.sqrt(jnp.square(r) + jnp.square(Z))
  k0_arr = jnp.array([k0])

#this summation is to be replaced by another function call which takes in these vectors
  term = R+Z+R1+k0_arr
  return term
```

This function is called by another function which vmapped or vectorized both give similar error

```
def compute_S(P,M): #other vectorized calculations here but this should work well with main above
  omega = 0.1
  val = main(P,P, omega)
  return val

quad_points = jnp.array([[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]])

S = jnp.zeros((50, 50))


vectorized_pairwise_compute_S = vmap(vmap(compute_S, (0, None)), (None, 0))
S = vectorized_pairwise_compute_S(quad_points, quad_points)
```

This gives me indexing error

```
IndexError: Too many indices for array: 1 non-None/Ellipsis indices for dim 0.
```

in the jnp.take() line

Answer (score 0):

The error is not coming from `jnp.take`, it is coming from this line:

```py
  Z = P[2] + M[2]
```

The problem is that when you mark a function with `@jnp.vectorize`, it is effectively computed element-by-element, so despite the fact that `P` and `M` are one-dimensional arrays when passed to the function, within the function `P` and `M` represent scalar values that cannot be indexed. For example:

```py
def f(x):
  print(f"{x.shape=}")
  print(f"{x[0]=}")

x = jnp.arange(4)
f(x)
# x.shape=(4,)
# x[0]=0

jnp.vectorize(f)(x)
# x.shape=()
# IndexError: Too many indices for array: 1 non-None/Ellipsis indices for dim 0.
```

It's not entirely clear to me what the intent of your code is, but if you meant to compute the `main` function over the full array inputs rather than element-by-element, then removing `@jnp.vectorize` should fix your problem.

Comment: hi, thank you for answering it quickly. This solves the issue but I get a different problem relating to index. If I fix this error, that is a problem and vice versa. I could not find a struve function implementation in Jax and I translated a code from matlab to jax to take the vector. I will make a new post. Thanks again!